# Discord python bot change user nickname when they chat something?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to change the user nickname when they chat **"Your Message"** but I got this error:

```py
File "main.py", line 301, in on_message
    await discord.Member.edit(nick="Cool Guy ")
TypeError: edit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Here is my code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('Your Message'):
        if message.channel.id == 921940384173674598:
            msg = '{0.author.mention} Cool'.format(message)
            await discord.Member.edit(nick="Cool Guy ")
            await message.channel.send(msg)
```

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback? Are you using this in a `Cog`?

Comment: `import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)`

Comment: You are trying to change the nickname of the `message.author`. `discord.Member` needs a member argument.

Comment: So what i can do ;-; ?

Comment: I literally gave you the answer. You need to change the `nick` of `message.author`, not `discord.Member`